# How do I fix xbindkeys keyboard to mouse button, repeating key presses when held?

Tags: mouse, logitech, xdotool, xbindkeys

I have a Logitech MX Revolution mouse that has a XF86Search keyboard key on it. I used xdotool to map it as a middle mouse button inside my xbindkeys file.

This mouse click no longer acts like a single button press, but instead flickers between on and off states when held down. This undesirable behavior is making it unusable to work with. For instance, it is preventing me from being able to pan the canvas in Graphic programs, or from panning around in Blender's viewport.

Using xev to to read the button mapping shows the alternating states flickering similar to keyboard press repeating keys.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue is? I once had this issue in my fresh install of Mint 18.2, but it went away after rebooting and recharging my batteries. This time this solution is not the answer as it happened again when updating Mint 18.2, and again on a fresh install of Ubuntu.

I unbound the search key in keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to stop a key-press from repeating is by adding the command xset -r keycode in the xbindkeys file. It behaves the same way as disabling key repeat in settings/keyboard.

the code in place looks like this:

```
"xset -r 225; xdotool mousedown 2"
    m:0x0 + c:225
    XF86Search

"xdotool mouseup 2"
    m:0x0 + c:225 + release
    XF86Search
```

While this solved this issue, the real problem I was having was not fixed, which was getting the search button to work perfectly as a middle mouse button in programs such as Blender. The above solution doesn't work well with the Shift modifier for a reason I don't understand.

The best solution for this problem was to forgo xbindkeys entirely, and instead enable middle click emulation by adding this code to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
# Enable mouse button emulation
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button_emulation = 1
# Set 2nd button to 217 - the middle button of MX Revolution mouse.
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button2_keycode = 217
```

After this, I had to create a udev file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` where it would call on a script whenever it would see my dongle plugged in. This script contains the command `sysctl --system` which is needed to enable the mouse 2 emulation. For some reason it is not enabled by default, which is something I would like to look into later.

This is my udev file specific to my logitech dongle:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="046d", RUN+="/bin/sh  /home/user/mouse-initialize-settings.sh"
```